# Force page number on top of inserted image

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, footer

I need to import a PDF full size to cover the whole page in the document but then I'm losing the page number. Is there any way to force LaTeX to insert a page number "on top" of the image?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\pagestyle{fancy}    

\begin{document}

\fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont 

Text without PDF
\clearpage

% Page with pdf 
\includepdf{sample.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This is the result with this test. I would like that the second page displays the page number as well:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default pdfpages sets the page style to empty. You can change that by setting an empty `pagecommand`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

% Page without page number
\includepdf{example-image-letter}
% Page with page number
\includepdf[pagecommand={}]{example-image-letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, so simple! Many thanks.